# Wicket: How can I rerender the current form without losing existing input?

Tags: ajax, forms, internationalization, wicket, preserve

I have a form with a combobox/drop down to select the user language. If the user changes the language, I'd like to update all the labels but leave the input elements alone.

In jQuery, I'd request a list of label IDs and the new texts via JSON and then use a loop like this:

```
var texts = {[ {id:'nameLabel', text:'First Name'}, {id:'familyLabel', text:'Family Name'} ]};
for( var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
    var item = texts[i];
    $('#'+item.id).text(item.text);
}
```

That would update all the labels without modifying anything else. How do I do this in Wicket?

[EDIT] What I tried:

```
        DropDownChoice<Locale> ddc = new DropDownChoice<Locale>(...);
        ddc.add( new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate( AjaxRequestTarget target ) {
                getSession().setLocale( language );
                for( MarkupContainer label : labels ) {
                    target.addComponent( label );
                }
            }
        });
```

This does change the labels but it also renders all the input fields again. I found no way to access the current values of the input fields.

[EDIT2] The list of labels is created like so:

```
        StringResourceModel usernameLabel = new StringResourceModel("usernameLabel", this, new Model<ValueMap>(map));
        labels.add(add(new Label("usernameLabel", usernameLabel)));
```

Comment: In this line: `for( MarkupContainer label : labels )` what is labels and how do you get it?

Comment: Labels is a list of all labels on the page. See EDIT2 for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
labels.add(add(new Label("usernameLabel", usernameLabel)));
```

You're not adding Label instances to 'labels', it's repeatedly adding the container you are adding it to (probably the Page instance). The method 'add()' doesn't return the component being added, it returns the container you are adding the components into.

Try changing it to:

```
Label label = new Label("usernameLabel", usernameLabel);
add(label);
labels.add(label);
```

Comment: You're right. I also needed to call `label.setOutputMarkupId( true );` but now, it works perfectly!